# Control Samsung's S Pen in Java

Tags: java, android, pen, samsung-mobile-sdk

I'm rather new to the Android App Development and I was wondering if it is kinda possible to `control the Samsung's S Pen` in `Java`???

For example, if I hold my `S Pen` near the screen of my Samsung device and press the `button of the S Pen`, that something would happen then. Just like an `onClick method for the S Pen` or something like that.

I didn't find anything useful in the internet about this. So, I wanted to ask you, guys, if you could tell me something about this or if you know a good website or so, where I could inform me.

I also heard something about an S Pen SDK but I don't really know what that is or what to do with it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How could you not find anything related to this? Why wouldn't you have tried searching for "S Pen SDK", which turns up all the Samsung links and docs regarding using the S Pen?

Comment: Yea, that could have been an option, right... Sorry! I was just looking for "controlling samsung's s pen in java" and stuff. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...

The S Pen SDK is, unsurprisingly, the way to control the S Pen.

Consider reading the documentation, which has examples, and an API reference.

http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs/S-Pen-SDK-2-3-Tutorial

Note that this is being rolled into the Mobile SDK:

http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk